# Unable to connect to MS SQL Server 2008 using a JAR from command prompt but runs successfully in Eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jar, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to `SQL Server 2008` using `sqljdbc4.jar` and could successfully connect using Eclipse.

But when i export my code as a JAR and try to run it using command prompt, i get error :

> D:\Eclipse\TestDBJar>java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -jar
>   TestDB.jar Apr 5, 2013 11:17:17 AM
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL INFO: java.security
>   path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security Security providers: [SUN
>   version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1. 6, SunJGSS
>   version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5, XMLDSig version 1.0, SunPCSC versio
>   n 1.6] SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509
>   key/trust factories,  SSLv3, TLSv1) SSLContext provider services:
>   [SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory   aliases:
>   [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1] , SunJSSE:
>   KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1] , SunJSSE:
>   Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2] , SunJSSE:
>   Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4] , SunJSSE:
>   Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
>   aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5,
>   1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1 .3.14.3.2.29] , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSASignat
>   ure , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 ->
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerF actoryImpl$SunX509 , SunJSSE:
>   KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManag
>   erFactoryImpl$X509 , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 ->
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustMana gerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory ,
>   SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX ->
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManager FactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
>   aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509] , SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSL ->
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl , SunJSSE:
>   SSLContext.SSLv3 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl ,
>   SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
>   , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 ->
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl , SunJSSE:
>   SSLContext.Default -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextI
>   mpl , SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 ->
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore ] java.ext.dirs: lib
>   **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption . Error: "RSA premaster secret error".**
>   ClientConnectionId:c0a357b6-e274-41b2-9fd a-7ef89ebdfb7a
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerC
>   onnection.java:1667)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
>
> ```
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLSer
> ```
>
> verConnection.java:1323)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConne
>   ction.java:991)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerCon
>   nection.java:827)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.
>   java:1012)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at TestDbConnection.main(TestDbConnection.java:13) **Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error**
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.(Unknown Sour
>   ce)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown 
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source
>   )
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>
> ```
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Un
> ```
>
> known Source)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Sou
>   rce)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Sou
>   rce)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
>
> ```
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyG enerator not available
>     at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(DashoA13*..)
>     at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
>     ... 17 more
> ```

I am providing an external lib folder having `sqljdbc4.jar` in it and running my JAR using 
`java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -jar TestDB.jar`

I have read through various posts but didn't work.

Comment: Do you actually want to connect to SQL over SSL? Or is that by accident? Because I guess there is probably some kind of complication with certificates that wouldn't exist if you weren't connecting over SSL.

Comment: No, i dont want to but is there a way to disable it. I have not mentioned it explicitly anywhere in code. For now, just have a code to establish connection using url, uname and pwd, thats it.

Comment: So you're not doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988945/java7-sqljdbc4-sql-error-08s01-on-getconnection

Comment: Thanks, i could solve the issue.

Comment: Do you want to tell everyone how? Then you can accept the answer for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting it as a `Runnable` JAR after selecting the option of `Copy required libraries next to generated JAR` solved the issue. A normal JAR, somehow, was not able to access the `lib` folder.