# JDBC SSL Connection with JTDS to MS SQL 2008 on IBM Websphere Application Server 6

Tags: sql-server, ssl, websphere, sqlexception, jtds

I'm using a WAS 6 (Websphere Applicatoin Server) and I'm trying to establish a connection to a MS SQL 2008 Server (via SSL).

```
IBM WebSphere Application Server - ND, 6.0.2.41

The Java Version on WAS 6 is 1.4.2
```

For the Data Source I use JTDS

```
 jtds-1.2.6.jar
```

Custom properites I set for the datasource:

```
serverName
portNumber
databaseName
enable2Phase
```

I'll always get following error when trying the "Test connection" on the Application Server.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection resetDSRA0010E: SQL-Status = 08S01, Fehlercode = 0
```

Any ideas?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a TCP/IP connection problem, not a datasource problem.

Have you checked that hostname and port are correct ?

Error 08S01 is defined as a Communication Link Error

Also you can check this : [Java7 sqljdbc4 - SQL error 08S01 on getConnection()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988945/java7-sqljdbc4-sql-error-08s01-on-getconnection)

Comment: Hmm, i also tried with the Websphere embedded JDBC Driver (connection works), but the MS SQL Server requires SSL and I'll get an SSL Error.  The datasource (user, pw, host, ..) are the same. So I don't think this is a TCP/IP connection problem :/